What does analyzing hard drive do if if I've unlocked all alt recipes for my current tier?
Normally if you research hard drives in MAM, you're presented recipes appropriate for your current advancement tier. Like, you won't get recipes that require a Blender if you've just unlocked Assembler. What happens if you have all alt recipes for current tier unlocked and research more? Do you get recipes 'above your pay grade', or do you get empty list like when you've researched all recipes there are at all, or what?
I'm currently on Tier 6, just unlocked the Manufacturer, and plan to end with temporary setups and start building permanent infrastructure soon, but before that I want to get all the good alt recipes - go on a big trek to get nearly every hard drive I can get by now. And I'm worried I'll overshoot with research and waste some hard drives.

The game won't let you waste them. According to the Wiki:

If a Hard Drive is researched, and there is nothing more available to unlock (either due to every recipe being unlocked or no more recipes being currently available due to milestone/MAM research progress), the Hard Drive will be returned after it is analyzed with the following message: "The analysis of Hard Drive is completed! No new research is available. Try again later after further progress. Your Hard Drive has been returned to you.".


Note that this answer links to the old Fandom wiki, which is no longer maintained. That content was removed from the current version of the wiki in https://satisfactory.wiki.gg/index.php?title=Hard_Drive&diff=prev&oldid=54416, although the edit summary of that edit suggests the answer is still the same.

@pppery ah, another Fandom site that's been abandoned l see. I guess the answer changes slightly, but essentially the same thing... the game won't let you. I am playing the game myself right now with the 1.0 release, I can test this but won't be for a while since I'm pretty far along and it'll take a long time to get all the recipes.

@TimmyJim The devs and community agreed to switch all the old fandom content over to the new official wiki at https://satisfactory.wiki.gg/wiki/Satisfactory_Wiki
